# Is there any inverse np.dot function?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

If I have two matrices a and b, is there any function I can find the matrix x, that when dot multiplied by a makes b? Looking for python solutions, for matrices in the form of numpy arrays.

Comment: For your information, your problem is to search the "inverse" of a matrix. if A*X = B, then X = (Ainverse) * B. "Ainverse" is noted A^(-1) (A to the power -1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem of finding X such as `A*X=B` is equivalent to search the "inverse of A", i.e. a matrix such as `X = Ainverse * B`.

For information, in math `Ainverse` is noted `A^(-1)` ("A to the power -1", but you can say "A inverse" instead).

In numpy, this is a builtin function to find the inverse of a matrix `a`:

```
import numpy as np

ainv = np.linalg.inv(a)
```

see for instance [this tutorial](https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/python-matrix-inverse.html) for explanations.

You need to be aware that some matrices are not "invertible", most obvious examples (roughly) are:

- matrix that are not square
- matrix that represent a projection

numpy can still approximate some value in certain cases.

Answer (score 3):

if `A` is a full rank, square matrix

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv

X = inv(A) @ B
```

if not, then such a matrix does not exist, but we can approximate it

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv

X = inv(A.T @ A) @ A.T @ B
```

Comment: What do you mean by "approximate"? Can you cite a reference of using this method? When will it work or not work? What kind of deviation from `B` am I to expect on the result of `A @ X` in that case?

Comment: @filbranden if `A` isn't full rank square then that means that there are either no nontrivial or infinite solutions to the problem `AX = B`. the second method is formally known as "normal method for linear regression" if the relation between `A` and `B` is  linear then the normal method would return one of the infinite solutions. there may be more methods, maybe with column/row reduction but im only familiar with this one.